# Get OneSignal notification count

Tags: java, android, push-notification, onesignal

I need to get OneSignal push notification and show on a badge icon with the number of notification which have not yet been seen. I don't know how I increase the number in badge when a push notification arrives and how I remove when he is visualized.

I use the ***implementation 'com.nex3z:notification-badge:1.0.2'*** to show my badges:

```
final NotificationBadge badge = findViewById(R.id.badge);
badge.setNumber(NUMBER_NOTIFICATION);
```

In another situation, I use this class to take the click action on notification:

```
public class NotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler {
        private AppCompatActivity application;
        Pessoa pessoa;

        public NotificationOpenedHandler(AppCompatActivity application){
            this.application = application;
        }

        @Override
        public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {
            pessoa = SharedPrefs.GetPessoa(application);

            //Pegar a ação de click do usuário na notificação
            OSNotificationAction.ActionType actionType = result.action.type;
            //Pegar conteudo adicional do push enviado
            JSONObject data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;

            //Verifica se o USUÁRIO clicou nos botões da notificação enviada
            if (actionType == OSNotificationAction.ActionType.ActionTaken || actionType == OSNotificationAction.ActionType.Opened) {
                Log.i("OneSignalExample", "Button pressed with id: " + result.action.actionID);

                //É feita a verificação se existe additionalData naquela notificação
                if (data != null && data.length() != 0) {
                    if (actionType.equals(OSNotificationAction.ActionType.ActionTaken)) {
                        //Verifica se o botao da notificação clicado foi o com o nome "VER PUBLICAÇÃO"
                        if (result.action.actionID.equals("VIEW_IDENTIFIER")) {
                            DataOneSignal dataMap = new DataOneSignal();
                            Type type = new TypeToken<DataOneSignal>() {
                            }.getType();
                            dataMap = (DataOneSignal) new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(String.valueOf(data), type);



                            switch (dataMap.getTipo()) {
                                //Caso a notificação seja para o PERFIL do USUÁRIO
                                case 0:
                                    Intent intentCase0 = new Intent(application, PerfilActivity.class)
                                            .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    intentCase0.putExtra("IdentificadorTarget", dataMap.getConteudo());
                                    intentCase0.putExtra("IdentificadorSelf",  this.pessoa.getIdentificador());
                                    application.startActivity(intentCase0);
                                    break;
                                //Caso a solicitação seja para o CHAT
                                case 1:
                                    Intent intentCase1 = new Intent(application, Chat_Activity.class)
                                            .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    intentCase1.putExtra("IdentificadorTarget", dataMap.getConteudo());
                                    intentCase1.putExtra("IdentificadorSelf",  this.pessoa.getIdentificador());
                                    application.startActivity(intentCase1);
                                    break;
                                //Recusado (provavelmente não vai usar)
                                case 2:
                                    Intent intentCase2 = new Intent(application, ContatosActivity.class)
                                            .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    application.startActivity(intentCase2);
                                    break;
                                //Caso a notificação seja para o FÓRUM
                                case 3:
                                    Intent intentCase3 = new Intent(application, DetalheTopico_Activity.class)
                                            .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    intentCase3.putExtra("TopicoId", dataMap.getConteudo());
                                    application.startActivity(intentCase3);
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Não foi possível encontrar a sessão.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    break;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                final CustomDialogClass cdd = new CustomDialogClass(application);
                cdd.setTitulo_txt("Fechar o aplicativo?");
                cdd.setPositiveButton("Sim", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        cdd.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                cdd.setNegativeButton("Não", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        cdd.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                cdd.show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The badge count is managed automatically for you by the OneSignal SDK. However, if you would like to manage them yourself, feel free to do so by taking a look at our [guide](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-customizations#section-app-icon-badge-counts).

**Edit:** to display inside the app you could retrieve the info from the [players endpoint](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#view-device)

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I need to show this count inside the app. You know how?

Comment: See above comment

Comment: But it only supports android 8+ what about older version?